# What does Milan's key open?

Tags: kingdom-come-deliverance

During the quest "Do me a favour - Punch me" I beat Milan and looted a door and trunk key off of him. What do these keys open?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go! Milan's house is where the "A" marker is. Just enter through where the arrow points and the door on the left is what you're looking for.

Edit: You can apparently open all the locked chests and doors in that house  with those keys.

[image: Milan's House]